# Techniques to pinpoint XSS injection point

Tags: xss

I am trying to figure out a way to understand which line of a JavaScript script is responsible for an XSS injection. Let's assume that I have a website that prompts for my name, and on some page, I set my name as something like `<script>alert("XSS")</script>`.

Later, I browse the website and somehow I see my payload being executed. I look at the source of the page, and I see that my payload is not there, so it should have been triggered by some JavaScript code. What is the best way to find which line of code is actually responsible for the injection? I usually look for `innerHTML(...)` calls, trying to figure out the ID of the element where my payload is injected, but it doesn't always work. I also tried using `<script>debugger;</script>` as payload, but I just see my script being debugged, and not the one responsible for the injection.

The best thing would be if there was a way to stop the execution of the script responsible for the injection right after the `alert()` is triggered, but I didn't find any way. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer here: If the script is executed with the help of `eval` (which is what happends if you use `html()` in jQuery 2.x), you can change the payload to something [throwing an error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw):

```
throw "XSS payload executed!";
```

Then fire up the console (F12 in most browsers). Browse the site until you trigger the payload. When the error is thrown you will have a nice little strack trace to inspect in the console.

Comment: After editing your question I noticed the JS was wrapped in `<script>` tags. Not sure if this will work then, but worht a try.

Comment: Hi Anders! Thansk for editing the question, it is much more clear now (I should have read it again before posting but I was in a rush!). I'll try your suggestion, which is in any case appreciated as in particular case, I had the payload in the `<script>` tag, but this is not always the case!

Comment: You will run into trouble with DOM-based XSS since you likely won't get a meaningful stack trace then.

Comment: @AlessandroGuagnelli Please let me know if it works or not if you try it!

Comment: @Arminius Hmm... I think it will if you are using jQuery (at least 2.x), since script tags are exectued with an eval. Not sure about other cases, will need to think and/or test some.

Comment: @Anders I'm thinking of something like a `innerHTML` sink. E.g. `document.body.innerHTML='<svg onload="throw 123">'` will probably not tell you where the flaw originated.

Comment: @Arminius Yeah, you are right. Will edit my answer.

Comment: @Anders thanks for the interest! Unfortunately that didn't work in this specific case, but I probably need to tweak the payload a little bit, which I'll do as soon as I have time to look into this again! I really appreaciated your help, and I'll find it useful for sure (as I didn't know about the throw technique)